# Pushing each returned object into the array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function where i'm getting the resource based on whether it's present or not. Everything gets displayed, but I need to push each resource in the resultArray. I'm using the forEach loop and it's not working, what am I missing?

```
renderResource = (resource = {}, i) => {
            let { resourceFile = "", resourceDescription= "" } = resource;

            if (!resourceFile) { return null }


            let resultArray = [];

            resource.forEach((resource, index) => {
                resultArray.push(resource);
            });
```

Comment: `resource` is not an array so not sure how you can loop over it.

Comment: `resource` is not an array so there is no `forEach` method on it as your code expects

Comment: Perhaps you intended this:
`Object.values(resource).forEach((resource, index) => {resultArray.push(resource);})`

Comment: Hi Dacre, that way I get the values of the resource that get pushed into the array. So I receive the arrays with the array values in them. But instead what I want is however many resource Objects get returned to be pushed into the array. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Resource is an object. Use for in method:

```
for (let key in resource) { 
  console.log(resource[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to loop over the values of `resource`. Since it's an Object, you can get them with `Object.values(resource)`.

Secondly, you should use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`, since `.forEach()` won't actually return anything.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  const [stuff, setStuff] = useState({ hello: 'hello', world: 'world'})

  return (
    Object.values(stuff).map(v => <div>{v}</div>)
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-udwz8g?file=index.js).

Comment: Hi Colin, that way I get the values of the resource that get pushed into the array. So I receive the arrays with the array values in them. But instead what I want is however many resource Objects get returned to be pushed into the array. Does it make sense?

Comment: Not sure I understand. In this case you just need `Object.values(resource)` and then push to the array.